# Помогите написать чат

Tags: java, сервер, чат, chat

Написал чат по типу один сервер и много пользователей. Сообщение от одного приходит на сервер, а он в свою очередь отправляет их всем остальным.

Загвоздка в методе:

```
private void whileChating() throws IOException {
        String message = "Вы подключены";
        printWriter.println(message + "\r\n");
        do {
            message = bufferedReader.readLine();
            printWriter.println("Сообщение получил");
            printWriter.println(message);
            System.out.println(message);
        } while (!message.equals("EXIT"));
    }
```

Метод выводит всем клиентам "Вы подключены", далее получает сообщение от нескольких клиентов выводит их в консоль и даже отправляет им "Сообщение получил", и отсылает это обратно только одному клиенту, как сделать, чтобы отсылалось всем?

Comment: `printWriter.flush();` вызовите после отправки второго сообщения.

Comment: Помогло, а как тогда сделать чтобы это сообщение отправлялось не тому же самому пользователю, а всем кто подключен к этому серверу?

Comment: У вас же там хранится где-то список всех подключений? Вот и отсылайте им всем. Это, во-первых. А во-вторых, лучше воспользуйтесь библиотекой готовой какой-нибудь для сети, вроде netty.

Comment: Пишу для обучения, как более грамотно создать список подключения без создания отдельного класса типа Network в котором инициализируются все потоки, сокеты и обрабатываются все подключения?

Comment: Например, в том месте, где происходит подключение с клиентом, добавлять соединение в отдельный список. При отключении удалять. И отправлять по необходимости сообщение всем соединениям.

Comment: Т.е. можно написать clients.add(new MyClient()); 
А дальше в цикле вызывать метод отправки сообщения?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создай коллекцию пользователей, чтобы при подключении пользователь добавлялся в эту коллекцию. И при отправке сообщения, пусть сервер берёт эту коллекцию и каждому пользователю отправляет данные(сообщение). За отправку данных будет отвечать отдельный метод в классе пользователя.

Comment: а что именно добавлять в коллекцию? Экземпляр класса клиента?

Comment: @Андрей - Да, пусть за дженерик выступает твой класс клиента